# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '31,950'

Tags: python, string, floating-point, valueerror

This is my code:

```
def check_price():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


    title = soup.find(id="itemTitle").get_text()
    price = soup.find(id="prcIsum").get_text()
    converted_price = float(price[4:10])
    converted_title = title[16:61]

    if(converted_price < 31.950):
        send_mail()

    print(converted_title)
    print(converted_price)

    if(converted_price > 31.000):
        send_mail()
```

This is the error I got

```
  File "C:/Users/Mario/PycharmProjects/Bitanga/AI.py", line 55, in <module>
    check_price()
  File "C:/Users/Mario/PycharmProjects/Bitanga/AI.py", line 20, in check_price
    converted_price = float(price[4:10])
  ValueError: could not convert string to float: '31,950'
```

Comment: Python only recognises floats with `.` as the decimal separator, per https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals. If you want to parse the string `'31,950'` to the floating point number `31.95`, you'll need to *replace* the comma. If it's supposed to be `31950.0`, you need to *remove* the comma.

Comment: '31,950' is not a valid float data.

Comment: replace `,` with `.` to convert string to float.

Comment: What do/don't you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace the `,` in the string `31,950` with a `.` so that python can recognize it as a decimal separator. Use:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


title = soup.find(id="itemTitle").get_text()
price = soup.find(id="prcIsum").get_text()
converted_price = float(price[4:10].replace(',', '.'))
converted_title = title[16:61]

if(converted_price < 31.950):
    send_mail()

print(converted_title)
print(converted_price)

if(converted_price > 31.000):
    send_mail()
```

Comment: Thanks! i have low reputation, so i cant give u a upvote.. but thanks alot! it helped <3

Comment: If an answer has solved your problem please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your string contains a character which cannot be converted ','.
For conversion from string to int, float, double, long ur string shld not have any character that doesnot looks like a number.
Or you can use a regex to remove all such characters so that u have only pure numbers in your string.
eg.

number = str[ /\d+(?:.\d+)?/ ]